# What is the meaning of ～たまえ?

Tags: grammar

While playing Final Fantasy 7, I came across the following text, which I think translates to something like:

> このせいせきでは、減給もありうると思ってくれたまえ
>   With these results, you can expect it likely there will also be a paycut!

But I'm wondering, what does the [～たまえ](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%88) mean in ～くれたまえ, ～与えたまえ and similar? Does it add emphasis or change the meaning in any way?

I looked in [Daijirin](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%88&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0) and [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%88&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0)'s entry for まえ, but I don't think I saw anything there (unless I'm missing something.)

Comment: も in 減給もありうる might be "even", like in "すらも/さえも" (not "also")?

Comment: hmm... You're probably right. But is there a way of telling the two meanings apart? For example, when "も" means "even", does the pitch change to be higher when spoken?

Comment: @cypher-san, Hehe, sorry but you can't tell the difference by the pitch. I think we read them the same way.^^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

たまえ=給え/賜え.
It is the imperative form of 給う/賜う/たまう(or たまふ/たもう), the archaic and honorific (尊敬語) form of [与]{あた}える "to give".
~~(して)くれたまえ is ~~(して)ください/~~(し)なさい, 与えたまえ is 与えてください/与えなさい in modern Japanese.

Comment: So just to make sure I understood, たまえ = ください, right?

Comment: @dotnetN00b-san, Yeah, according to my dictionaries (modern Japanese and archaic Japanese), ~たまえ can translate to ~ください/~なさい.